# Jenkins Promotions vs Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, continuous-delivery

We've been starting to link build&test&deployment jobs together into sequential tasks (for now as simple as: build -> run tests -> if tests pass -> deploy) and had some experiments with [Promoted Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) and [Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/).

Is our understanding correct that Promoted builds and Pipelines are two different separate strategies to Continuous delivery? Or, can they still be used together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just configured `promoted builds plugin` and the `pipelines` plugin and found at least one difference between the two plugins, i.e. the first plugin seems to be able to allow manually deploy of certain stages, while the pipelines plugins seems to deploy everything automatically.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41043750/2777965), manual deploy of a certain stage seems to be missing.

In summary, it seems that it would be nice to combine the two plugins as it could be handy to have a manual check before deploying to production, i.e. a human has to press the button in order to deploy to production.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260075/2777965) it is not possible to combine both plugins at the moment.